# Increment through int[] as an int

Tags: java

So during a homework assignment I made a method that would increment through an integer array as if it were an integer. So what I mean by that is that the index of the int[] would represent the digits in a number.

for example:

```
int[] digits;
digits = new int[4]
```

this would be a 4 digit number. index 0 being the 1000's place, index 1 being the 100's place, index 2 being the 10's place and index 3 being the 1's place.
So the method I made increments through that array like this:
0000, 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004, --> 0010, 00011, ----> 9999.

```
public void increment(){

        if(digits[3] <= 8){
            digits[3]++;
        }
        else{
            digits[3] = 0;
            if(digits[2] <= 8){
                digits[2]++;
            }
            else{
                digits[2] = 0;;
                if(digits[1] <= 8){
                    digits[1]++;
                }
                else{
                    digits[1] = 0;
                    if(digits[0] <= 8){
                        digits[0]++;
                    }
                    else{
                        digits[0] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is how would I go about making a method that does the same thing but the method requires an index to be passed in.

for example:

```
public void increment(int index){

      //increments through index number of digits.
}
```

So something like this:

```
increment(7);
```

would yield this: 0000000, 0000001, 0000002, 0000003, --> 0000009, 0000010, 0000011, -----> 9999999.

This is personally for my own satisfaction so any help would be great =)

Comment: is using int array a requirement? isn't it much simpler to have a single counter and you output the number with padded zeros?

Comment: try doing it recursively

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

[**Live demo**](https://ideone.com/wR25fs)

Example for reference:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
[0,4]
[0,5]
[0,6]
[0,7]
[0,8]
[0,9]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
[1,5]
[1,6]
...
```

- First create a 2D array where each row represent a number with n digits. We can get the 2D array height by doing 10^n because we have n digits and 10 possibilities for each digit (0-9)
- We can notice a pattern in the numbers generated which is the rightmost column switches digit every one iteration, the second rightmost digit switches digit every 10 iterations, the third one switches digit each 100 iteration etc... so the kth rightmost index switches iteration every 10^k iterations. This is noted by the variable `level`. Also some iterations on the digits can be omitted because we know that some digits will not increase until a specific row (example the leftmost digit will not increase for row 1 if `n` > 1). You can get the width of digits to loop on by doing `log10(row)` which will give you the number of digits in the integer `row` minus one. This is called `width` in the code.
- Then all we need to do is check if now it's time to switch `row%level == 0` then we increment the value from above level by one, otherwise we just copy the same value from row above.

  ```
  public static void numbers(int n) {
          int nums[][] = new int[(int)Math.pow(10, n)][n];
          for(int row=1; row < nums.length; row++) {
              int width = (int) Math.log10(row);
              for(int col = nums[row].length-1; col >= nums[row].length-1-width; col--) {
                  int level = (int) Math.pow(10, n - col - 1);
                  if(row % level == 0) {
                      nums[row][col] = (nums[row-level][col]+1) % 10;
                  } else {
                      nums[row][col] = nums[row-1][col];
                  }
              }
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums[row]));
          } 
  }
  ```

Comment: Using that are you able to access each individual number? for example my homework was to write a program that would generate a number that met certain conditions: All 4 digits must be different, all digits have to equal 27, the number must be odd and the number in the 1000s place is 3 times the number in the 10s place. I used a series of if statements to do that pointing at a certain indexes in the array.

Comment: No this will not work with conditions. The question does not mention that, therefore all answers here will not take that into consideration. I suggest you create another question for each condition because you can solve each case efficiently using math (combination and permutations) to guess the result length.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: `int [] = digits;` is a syntax error; remove the `=`.

The `increment` routine needs access to the array of digits, and in Java arrays 'know' their bounds so you don't need a separate parameter or variable for the length. Given that, the classic hacker method (from the age of the dinosaurs when hacker meant good) is:

```
void increment (int[] digits){
    for( int i = digits.length; --i>=0 && ++digits[i]==10; ) digits[i]=0;
}
# alter the 10 to change radix, or make it variable if desired
```

This mimics the procedure you learned in elementary school (or at least I did): start at the rightmost digit, add one, if it doesn't overflow you're done, if it does overflow change it to zero and move one place to the left except stop when you are already at the left end and can't move further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is quiet simple and readable:

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        increment(7);
    }

    static void increment (int index){

        index = Math.abs(index) ;
        int[] digits = new int [index];
        Arrays.fill(digits, 0); //initialize array with 0

        for( int i = index-1; i>=0 ; i--) {//loop over all digits

            for(int digit = 0; digit <=9 ; digit++) {//increment each 

                digits[i] = digit;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits));
            }
        }
    }
}
```